# The data list is not appear in display.html using Flask app

Tags: html, css, flask, web-scraping

After scraping from a website, I have appended the data to a list on my scraper.py page. The coding will be like below:

scraper.py: (here it return data)

```
data.append({
                "Name": name,
                "Title": title,
                "Location": location,
                "Experiences": experiences,
                "Education": educations,
                "Certifications": certifications,
                "Skills": skills,
                "Languages": languages
            })
```

Then in my flask application, named "app.py" I called the display.html page, but when the page is displayed on the web page, the data is not appear. I have checked that the data list is contains value by print(data)

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pandas as pd
from scraper import scrape_data

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home_page.html')

@app.route('/upload_page')
def upload_page():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    data = scrape_data(df)
    return render_template('display.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[Here is the screenshot of display.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjgBw.png)

The coding for display.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scraped Information</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Scraped Information</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Experiences</th>
          <th>Education</th>
          <th>Certifications</th>
          <th>Skills</th>
          <th>Languages</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.experiences }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.educations }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.certifications }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.skills }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.languages }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What does your display.html look like?

Comment: Hi! I have attached the screenshot of the display.html and the coding.

Comment: Please show all of `scrape_data.py`. It doesn't return data or contain the definition of the function you're calling. Otherwise, the calling code looks fine and doesn't reproduce the problem on its own. See [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen the scrape code working fine because when i print(data), it shows the output for all the name, title, and etc.

Comment: Are you clarifying that the output looks OK when you `print(data)` right after `data = scrape_data(df)`, or somewhere else? That's fine, but please show what that data looks like then. If it's a list of dictionaries, then you'll need to use `item["Name"]` to access the key in your template. Your server logs would show the KeyError.

Comment: @ggorlen Omg thank you. My problem is solved with item["Name"].